# Connecting Sybase from Lua

Tags: lua, sybase, luasql

According this link [LuaSQL](https://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/doc/us/manual.html) LuaSql has plans for a driver for Sybase. The doc is not a recent one. So can anybody please tell me if it was indeed launched.
If not what would be a work-around for connecting  Sybase from Lua?

Comment: I use Lua-ODBC(https://luarocks.org/modules/moteus/odbc) to work with Sybase ASA 9/11.

Comment: Thanks @moteus . I will need to do that using apache's mod_lua . Can you point me to some documents guiding how to do an end to end set up for that?